# Google Play Services and Play Store crashing

Tags: google-play-store, crashes, google-play-services

I have very little internal memory (user memory 150mb), so after the auto update of Play Service and the Play Store, I took a back up (using ES File Explorer). I have root access, so I pasted those back ups in the `/system/app` folder. After that I restarted my phone, and that's when the problem started. The Play Store opens but can't see a thing, and Play Services crashes every time.

What I have done:

- I installed 3 version of the Play Store. No positive result.
- Installed the latest version of Play Services. No positive result.
- Searched many blogs. They say it might happen as not com.android.gapps, but I can see the service running. However, after installing Play Services, both Play Services and gapps are crashing.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ouch...

So, I'm unclear on what exactly you meant by "took a backup"...

This sounds like a Google Play Services mismatch - either mismatched with the Android version you're running or different app versions installed.

I'm gonna need more info to troubleshoot it, but just a couple shots in the dark here:

Play Service and Store don't like being messed around with. Just, in general. That's why they're usually installed via a recovery zip file.
If you moved the latest version of Play Store (`vending.apk`) and Play Services (`gms.apk`) from userspace to `/system/app`, that's most likely what caused this.
Hopefully, you backed up the versions in `/system/app`. The Play apps usually rely on library files (.so files), which are sometimes updated in userspace. You're probably getting a mismatch between those.

If you backed up the previous copies, recovering from this is simple. Just restore the backups. If you didn't, this may be more difficult. What device are you on? Also, what Android version, and are you running stock or a custom ROM? (if you don't know the answer, you're probably on stock)

Comment: I m on stock version. Its ICS (4.0.4).

Comment: I had did the same for earlier versions of Play Store and Play Services. So I did not store the earlier backups.

Answer (score 0):

Any time I've integrated Play Services updates into my ROM I've had such crashes.  Clearing the data for Play Services, Play Store, and anything else related fixes the issue.